# Angular 6 - Convert JSON to array

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, angular6

Hellog guys , i am trying to convert json data to object array for add these data to kendo grid but i am getting this error

**Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined**

This error mean my data format isn't correct !.

This how data in json file are :

```
[
  {
    "orderNumber": 1,
    "orderTable": "905503111-9",
    "orderDescription": "Nullam porttitor lacus at turpis. Donec posuere metus vitae ipsum. Aliquam non mauris.",
    "orderDate": "5/4/2018",
    "orderPrice": 79
  }
]
```

But i want them to be like this :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "orderNumber": 1,
      "orderTable": "905503111-9",
      "orderDescription": "Nullam porttitor lacus at turpis. Donec posuere metus vitae ipsum. Aliquam non mauris.",
      "orderDate": "5/4/2018",
      "orderPrice": 79
    }
  ],
}
```

Here an example of how i am accessing json file (orders.ts)

```
import { orders } from './orders';
import { employees } from '../employee/employees';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order',
  templateUrl: './order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order.component.css']
})
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {
  public result;
  public data = orders;
}
```

I tried many solutions like json.parse() and json.stringify() but didn't get what i need.

Note : I am using json file (orders.ts) that exist in my project.

Comment: Please post how you are consuming this json (a service? importing it from an external file?). In other words, show your javascript/angular code.

Comment: no from a file that exist in my project .

Comment: btw i just edited the post if you like to recheck

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
  {
    "orderNumber": 1,
    "orderTable": "905503111-9",
    "orderDescription": "Nullam porttitor lacus at turpis. Donec posuere metus vitae ipsum. Aliquam non mauris.",
    "orderDate": "5/4/2018",
    "orderPrice": 79
  }
];
var newData = {
    "orderNumber": 1,
    "orderTable": "905503111-9",
    "orderDescription": "Nullam porttitor lacus at turpis. Donec posuere metus vitae ipsum. Aliquam non mauris.",
    "orderDate": "5/4/2018",
    "orderPrice": 79
  };

data.push(newData)
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it simply like this and make sure name is same as data

```
 data=[
 {
"orderNumber": 1,
"orderTable": "905503111-9",
"orderDescription": "Nullam porttitor lacus at turpis. Donec posuere metus vitae  ipsum. Aliquam non mauris.",
"orderDate": "5/4/2018",
"orderPrice": 79
}
];
let d={data}

console.log(d)
```

or

```
let d={}
 d.data=[
{
"orderNumber": 1,
"orderTable": "905503111-9",
"orderDescription": "Nullam porttitor lacus at turpis. Donec posuere metus vitae ipsum. Aliquam non mauris.",
"orderDate": "5/4/2018",
"orderPrice": 79
}
]
console.log(d)
```

you will get the desired output